# Necessary to use Dir.pwd inside Dir[] when globing several directories?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a Ruby gem. In the lib/my_gem.rb root file, I have this:

```
require_relative "my_gem/practices/practice"
```

But that file practice.rb requires several *.rb files in a number of subdirectories in the practices/ directory. So at the bottom of the file, I do this:

```
Dir["#{Dir.pwd}/lib/my_gem/practices/**/*.rb"].each do |file|
  require file
end
```

It works, but when I look at other gems like Rails, I notice they never use `Dir.pwd`. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` tries to load relative filespecs in the context of each directory in the `$LOAD_PATH`. When a gem is `require`'d, its lib directory is added to this load path. This enables the use of `require` instead of `require_relative`. For example, in my rails console, I see this output included in the output of `puts $LOAD_PATH`:

```
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.4/lib
/Users/kbennett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/loofah-2.2.2/lib
```

In your case, you're not requiring the gem when you run the code. So you need to either use `require_relative` or add your lib directory to the load path explicitly. I prefer the former approach; it feels cleaner to me.

Using `File.dirname`, `File.join`, and `__FILE__`, you can compute the directory from which to build your filespec to pass to `require`. You can also use `Dir.pwd`, but that will break if you run your code from a different directory.

So in your my_gem.rb you can have something like the code below (normally I would not use so many intermediate variables but they're useful here for illustrative purposes):

```
this_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
rb_filemask = File.join(this_dir, 'practices/**/*.rb')
rb_files = Dir[rb_filemask]
rb_files.each { |filespec| require filespec }
```

Comment: No, your first option does not work. It gives me error "cannot load such file -- lib/my_gem/practices/texas/medical_practice.rb"

Comment: But when I add #{Dir.pwd}/ it works, as I mentioned in question.

Comment: Sorry. I've drastically modified my answer. Please take a look and see if that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency is only as such: file A needs file B, and file B needs file C, then file A should not take care of file C. The requirement for file C should be written on file B, not file A.

In your case, requiring the `*.rb` files in subdirectories should be written in `practice.rb`, not in `lib/my_gem.rb`.